# Firebase Google sign in error after email sign in

Tags: firebase, authentication

Firebase Javascript SDK's `getRedirectResult()` silently fails to sign the user in after the same user signed in with email. Firebase's setting to link accounts that use the same email is enabled, which allows the same email address to be tied to a single user identity even when using different sign in methods.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Turn on "Link accounts that use the same email" Firebase authentication setting.
2. Sign in via a Google email by calling `isSignInWithEmailLink()`.
3. Sign out via `signOut()`.
4. Sign in with Google by calling `signInWithRedirect()` using `GoogleAuthProvider`.
5. Once  redirection is complete call `getRedirectResult()`.

### what should happen

After successful redirection `getRedirectResult()` should return a valid `UserCredential`, triggering `onAuthStateChanged()` accordingly.

### What actually happens

`getRedirectResult()` returns `null` instead.

### Additional context

I noticed Firebase SDK creates two separate instances of its IndexDB named "firebaseLocalStorageDb" but with different origins, one is the application's origin (http://localhost:3000) and another one with origin "https://.firebaseapp.com"

Also, if instead of linking accounts that use the same email is disabled, this stops happening but this changes the internal structure of the UserCredential.

Any help is appreciated.